# Convert XML to Avro and generate AVRO schema

Tags: java, xml, avro, converters

What can I use, in Java, to convert XML to Avro and also generate automatically the avro schema?

Answer (score 1):

I found simple git project for xml-avro conversion [here](https://github.com/elodina/xml-avro)

and Detailed article [here](https://www.infoq.com/articles/AVROSchemaJAXB/)

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you could also try this simple tool. https://github.com/romaanankin/avro-schema-manager

just fill simple.CSV like in test and you got Avro schemas from that.