# Using Java programming, How can I convert XML file into Avro file?

Tags: java, xml, avro

I am new to java and I need to input XML file to a java code that gives Avro as output, cannot find a working example on the net.

Found this Github repo -- https://github.com/elodina/xml-avro in the existing thread -- [Convert XML to Avro and generate AVRO schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005465/convert-xml-to-avro-and-generate-avro-schema) - but I am not able to run it as I am not acquainted with the execution procedure and I cannot understand properly the instruction written in the above mentioned github page. could u please write me a more elaborated instruction for executing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a while since I used Apache Camel for this,
but it was out-of-the box.
Add Apache Camel dependency and voila!
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/dataformats/avro-dataformat.html